# How are unicoins generated?

Tags: discussion, unicoins, unicorns

How are unicoins generated? Is it in a bitcoin type fashion with hashing or how else?

Comment: unicoins=unicoins+1; These bitcoin people just have too much time on their hands

Comment: Since they're found in rocks, I assumed they were the fossilized remains of ancient unicorns.

Comment: 1 unicoin = 1 entry in a rainbowtable

Comment: "fossilized remains of ancient unicorns" - Oh dear, I thought unicorns to be immortal?

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz Like most immortals, they can be *killed*, they just don't *naturally* die. The only usual cause for this is other unicorns, and mostly during mating season.

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz Perhaps like Elves they can die of grief and weariness :(

Comment: May I provide this link for the most common casuses of Elf death http://www.funnyordie.com/articles/40faba82ca/most-common-elf-deaths

Comment: +1 Finally, an intellectual, interesting question. That has a solid answer.

Answer (score 5):

They aren't generated! They are found naturally in rocks in Unicorn Land! Although those rocks are generated here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unicoin/rock.

Comment: Well the rock are valid [base58 address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) with version=30, so it's technically valid dogecoin wallet address. Within one rock there can be 0,1, or 6 unicoins. Mining the same address again always gives 0. Wonder if the value is somehow stored inside the rock address.

Answer (score 1):

When a mommy and daddy unicorn love each other very much...

Comment: ...they sit in the sunshine together and are happy forever. The end.

Answer (score 0):

Since the failure of the scientists to save unicorn from extinction they decide to turn they bones to coins. And this is how unicoins came to us. Every time you break a unicorn bone, aka rocks, you get a random number of unicoins, the number is deliver from the size of the original unicorn, if he eat many carrots and had a big belly his bones will be bigger and more unicoins will be generated. Unfortunately the middle east unicorns did not eat carrots due to the competition with camels so no unicoins are generated when croaking their bones/stones.